# Supremum and Infimum of sequences

Tags: proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

I'm trying to understand the following examples:

Let T be a sequence such that $ T = \{1 - \frac{1}{n}\}$

It seems obvious that $\sup(T) = 1$

My proof for the supremum was:

For any $u < 1$ we have $\epsilon = 1 - u > 0$

By the Archimedean property there exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n} < 1 - u$.

Or equivalently, $u < 1 - \frac{1}{n}$. Thus u is not an upper bound.

But I'm having trouble determining and proving $\inf(T)$. Could someone help me out?

---

Also, I'm completely lost on this example:

Let K = $[-\pi,\pi] \cap \mathbb{Q}$

I said that this is equivalent to saying:

K = $ \{k \in \mathbb{Q} : -\pi \leq k \leq \pi \}$

So from there I said $\inf(K) = -\pi$ and $\sup(K) = \pi$, but I'm not sure on how to go about proving them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The infimum is 0 because when n=1 you get 1-1=0.